# NSNumber becomes nil when used in NSDictionary initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, null, nsnumber

I have the following code block:

```
NSNumber* dayNsNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:dayNumber+1];
NSLog(@"dayNsNumber: %d", [dayNsNumber intValue]);

if(boolVar){

    UIAlertView* success = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d!", dayNumber+1] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Star", nil];
    [success show];
    NSLog(@"dayNsNumber: %d", [dayNsNumber intValue]);
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            dayNsNumber, "Day Number",
            [self getCurrentLocalDate], @"Date",
            [self getCurrentLocalTime], @"Time",
         nil];
}
```

What happens is that when I run the code, it hangs upon initialization of the `params` `NSDictionary` and says that `dayNsNumber` is `nil`.

Xcode displays a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1).

**How do I solve thie issue? I would like to add the `dayNsNumber` to my `params` dictionary.**

Additionally, here are `getCurrentLocalDate` and `getCurrentLocalTime`:

```
-(NSString*)getCurrentLocalDate;{ 
    NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd-MM-yyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"todayString: \"%@\"", todayString);
    return todayString;

}

-(NSString*)getCurrentLocalTime;{
    NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"HH:mm:ss zzz" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"timeString: \"%@\"", timeString);
    return timeString;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the key: `"Day Number"` should be `@"Day Number"`.

Also note that you can now use the new syntax for your numbers, arrays, and dictionaries. For example, this

```
NSNumber* dayNsNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:dayNumber+1];
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
NSNumber* dayNsNumber = @(dayNumber+1);
```

and the dictionary initialization can be done like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"Day Number" :   dayNsNumber
,   @"Date"       : [self getCurrentLocalDate]
,   @"Time"       : [self getCurrentLocalTime]
};
```

Comment: Bejesus how could I have been so dumb. Thanks. And another thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hi. I got back to thinking about this question again. Do you think you can explain to me why Xcode shows that `dayNsNumber` was `nil`. Could you explain the nature of the compiler or in some low-level explanation why the error was shown as so?

Comment: @brain56 The short answer is that the stack gets messed up. The sequence of objects up to a `nil` is passed through the mechanism that is used for passing variable number of parameters. The compiler does not perform additional checks, because parameters are untyped. The receiving function cannot perform the checks at all, so it assumes that everything that is passed in is a pointer to an Objective C object. When you pass a C string, undefined behavior happens in the receiving function, and the stack gets messed up. That's why when you examine `dayNsNumber` it looks incorrect in the debugger.

Comment: That's food for thought for today. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[params setValue:[daysNumber stringValue] forKey:@"Day Number"];
```